# Word for the sound made while vomiting

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, onomatopoeia

Which word can I use to describe the sound somebody makes while vomiting? Is *burp* the right word for it?

Comment: _retch_ would be a more accurate word than _burp_ (although neither of those describes the sound, so I'm just leaving this as a comment).

Comment: If you're looking for an existing word for the *sound*, then the sky's the limit unless you're specific. What aspect of the sound are you describing: the noise produced physically in the throat and mouth (e.g. *gurgle*), the figurative quality of the noise (e.g. *horrible*), or something else entirely? Can you please add some additional context on how you plan to use this word in a sentence?

Comment: @J.R. I didn't see your comment until after I submitted my answer, but I agree with retch. I've added some possible contexts for the use of retch in reference to the sound instead of the action.  What makes retch appropriate here is that it defines the activity of vomiting, not just the end result.

Comment: whatever the right word is, 'burp' is -not- one of them. A burp and 'burp' as a sound to describe that are only associated with air coming out. If anything else comes out, it is not a burp at all.

Comment: @Mitch: Unless the one burping is less than a year old.  At that age, the lines between burping and puking are much more blurry and muddled.

Comment: @J.R. Point well taken. But strictly, the part that is a burp and the part that is vomit are distinct. It's not an ambiguity in the words but a difficulty in recognizing which one (or both) applies.

Comment: For the people suggesting "burp", do you possibly mean "urp"?

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh Buick

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would say that the sound made by vomiting is **[retching](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retch)**.  I've also seen **retching noises** or **the sound of retching** used in print to specify the sound instead of the action.

[Merriam-Webster Online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retch) gives this definition:

> transitive verb
> : vomit 1
> intransitive verb
> : to make an effort to vomit; also : vomit

For example:

> I was having a great time until I heard the sound of retching and saw that my neighbor had just vomited on my new rug.  I'm sending him the cleaning bill.

Ngram:
[image: Google Ngram chart showing frequency of 'retching noises' and 'sound of retching', both of which begin to increase in the early 20th-century]

Comment: I would say that "retching" is the verb that describes the sound you make just *before* you vomit, whereas "[blargh](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/89697/109197)" is the actual sound itself... **>:-)**

Answer (score 16):

*Blech* or *blarg(h)*, with extra *H*s for extra effect.

Some Google Image Search results for *blargh*:

[image: Blargh]

[image: Blargh]

[image: Blargh]

Comment: Great word & images - +1

Comment: Shoop da whoop isn’t really vomiting.

Comment: But how is it pronounced?

Answer (score 7):

[Here are some 147 terms for ‘to vomit’](http://thedabbler.co.uk/2011/02/green%E2%80%99s-dictionary-of-slang-vomit/). Interestingly, it says *57 of these, i.e. approximately 38%,  come from or are primarily used in Australia*.

[Here are dozens more](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/thesaurus/words+meaning+to+vomit.html), but focussing on the sound itself, I think the most onomatopoeic one is...

> [call for **huey**](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/call-for-huey)

Another high-scorer on the "onomatopoeic scale" is [**hurling** [over the toilet bowl]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hurled%20over%20the%20bowl%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22hurling%20over%20the%20toilet%22&hl=en&tbo=1&sa=X&ei=9XSRUJnmHe-Y1AXhvIDYBQ&ved=0CDMQ6wYwAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=9c5d93062e4b9fa0&bpcl=36601534&biw=1302&bih=870).

Comment: Voting this one up, because I think it is wrong to imply that there is *one* word in English for this. A person is supposed to just pick a nice evocative one appropriate to the situation from our huge menu of them. I guess this probably says something profound about our culture....

Comment: @T.E.D.: I almost voted to close because I knew I'd easily be able to find dozens of terms meaning "to vomit", making it a non-constructive "list" type of question. But on reflection I have to admit I don't know *any* "word" with any currency that actually means *the **sound** of vomiting*. I'm not sure there's any equivalent to, say, the ***screech** of nails on a blackboard, the **moo** of a cow,* or *the **hiss** of air escaping*. All I know is "retch" doesn't seem very onomatopoeic to me.

Comment: It does to me. Perhaps we in the USA do it with a different accent? :-)

Comment: I guess they are either more experienced in Australia; or more creative; or perhaps both.

Comment: "Calling Ralph on the big white telephone..."

Answer (score 1):

GACK maybe? And yea, it's totally got to be in all caps. INTERJECTIONS RULE!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if [boke](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boke#Scots) counts as English (it's Scots) -- but it's a great word. [Burp](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burp) is not the right word at all -- it's a completely different function of the body.

*Puke*, *barf* and *ralph* are used in certain regions. They all mean "vomit" (the verb, not the sound) but are so onomatopoeic that to my mind they apply to the sound as well.

Comment: I also consider *hurl* onomatopoeic. Perhaps *spew* might count, as well. Depending on the context, you could even mint your own word (e.g. I might write *gluphc* in a comic book setting).

Comment: The questioner doesn't ask for onomatopoeic words.  *boke* is a word for vomiting, not *for* the sound it makes.  It *replicates* the sound it makes, but that is not quite the same thing.  Of course, the OP may not have been clear...

Answer (score 0):

You may use **[kecking](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keck)**.

The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=keck) of this verb is as follows:

> "to make a sound as if to vomit," 1530s, echoic.

Answer (score -1):

*Sploosh*: the sound as it hits the ground and just trickles everywhere.

Answer (score -2):

Also *bleagh*. You know the sound you hear before your carpet is ruined.