# Is "mellifluous" onomatopoeic?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, onomatopoeia

> mel·lif·lu·ous  /məˈliflo͞oəs/
>   Adjective:
>   (of a voice or words) Sweet or musical; pleasant to hear.

As in the title: is "mellifluous" onomatopoeic or is the definition of onomatopoeia stricter than that?

Comment: Tangentially, or perhaps metaphorically, related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/23529 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/89691 http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you are looking for is not *onomatopoeic*, but rather  either of *autological* or *homological*, as described in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/11422/2085).  Both  mean a word that is self-descriptive.  *Mellifluous* is autological because its name sounds so sweet.

Comment: I don't even think it sounds sweet.  Before I knew what it meant I always thought it sounded like something you'd call a gang of bullies.  "What are those mellifluous kids up to now."  I still avoid using it today because it's not a well-known word and I wouldn't want people to misinterpret it the way I did.

Comment: It sounds sweet for phoneaesthetic reasons: it has no unvoiced stops (nor any at all), and uses linguals and nasals and fricatives and sibilants. Compare *cellar door, Melian, Lúthien, Doriath, Beleriand, Valinor*.

Answer (score 2):

A word is generally considered onomatopoeic when it has its origins in the actual sound it describes. Common examples are *buzz, whoosh* and *cuckoo*. *Melliflouous* comes from Latin words meaning ‘honey’ and ‘flow’. If the sound of the word in any way echoes its sense, it does so entirely fortuitously.

Answer (score 1):

A word like *mellifluous* describes the sound. An onomatopoeic word like *buzz* **imitates** the sound.

*Mellifluous* is not onomatopoeic because it does not imitate the sound it describes.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mellifluous&allowed_in_frame=0):

> **mellifluous** (*adj*.)
>   early 15c., "sweet, pleasing" (of an odor, a style of speaking or writing, etc.), from L.L. *mellifluus* "flowing with (or as if with) honey," from L. *mel* (gen. *mellis*) "honey" (related to Gk. *meli* "honey;" see Melissa) + -*fluus* "flowing," from *fluere* "to flow" (see *fluent*). Related: Melifluously; melifluousness.

In order for it to be onomatopoeic, at some point in its history it would have had to be imitative of some sound made. As far as I can tell, honey does not make a sound. Ever.

Comment: Evidence is starting to emerge that some people think [nom nom](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=nom+nom+honey&oq=nom+nom+honey&aqs=chrome.0.57j60.786&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is the sound of honey (others think it's *nom nom **nom*** :)